# Debug Assertion Failed: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData) C++

Tags: c++, debugging, random, assertion

I'm a beginner in C++, and I tried to write a program that randomly generates me an episode from one of my favorite serials, or absolute randomly, but when I debug it, this error always come up.

The code is OK, if it's not in Win32 Form app, it works.

Could you please help me?

My code of List item:

```
Void pro::Form1::keres(string sori) {


int k=0;
vector<string> a;
srand (time(NULL));
string desti = "d:\\Filmek\\Sorozatok\\" + sori + "\\*";
WIN32_FIND_DATA search_data;
int s;

memset(&search_data, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));
HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(desti.c_str(), &search_data);

while(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    a.push_back(search_data.cFileName);
    k++;
    if(FindNextFile(handle, &search_data) == FALSE)
        break;
}

s = rand() % (k-2);
cout<<a[s+2]<<endl;
desti = "d:\\Filmek\\Sorozatok\\" + sori + "\\" + a[s+2] + "\\*";
handle = FindFirstFile(desti.c_str(), &search_data);
k = 0;

while(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    a.push_back(search_data.cFileName);
    k++;
    if(FindNextFile(handle, &search_data) == FALSE)
        break;
}
s = rand() % (k-2);
string run = "cd " + desti + " & start " + a[s+2];
system(run.c_str());
a.clear();
}

Void pro::Form1::kereses(string film) {

int q=0;
int w=0;
int e=0;

int a;
int s;
int d;

vector<string> y;
vector<string> x;
vector<string> v;
srand (time(NULL));

string desti = "d:\\Filmek\\" + film + "\\*";
WIN32_FIND_DATA search_data;

memset(&search_data, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));
HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(desti.c_str(), &search_data);

while(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    y.push_back(search_data.cFileName);
    q++;
    if(FindNextFile(handle, &search_data) == FALSE)
        break;
}

a = rand() % (q-2);
desti = "d:\\Filmek\\" + film +"\\" + y[a+2] + "\\*";
handle = FindFirstFile(desti.c_str(), &search_data);
y.clear();
q = 0;

while(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    x.push_back(search_data.cFileName);
    w++;
    if(FindNextFile(handle, &search_data) == FALSE)
        break;
}

s = rand() % (w-2);
desti = "d:\\Filmek\\" + film +"\\" + y[a+2] + "\\" + x[s+2] + "\\*";
handle = FindFirstFile(desti.c_str(), &search_data);
x.clear();
w = 0;

while(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    v.push_back(search_data.cFileName);
    e++;
    if(FindNextFile(handle, &search_data) == FALSE)
        break;
}
d = rand() % (e-2);
string run = "cd " + desti + " & start " + v[d+2];
system(run.c_str());
v.clear();
e=0;

}
```

Comment: Fyi, your logic for attempting to skip of parent and self-aliases is hideous. Utilize the `dwFileAttributes` member of `WIN32_FIND_DATA` to *selectively* push only file names, directories, or whatever your filtering down into your containers. [See here for possible mask bits to test.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117(v=vs.85).aspx). And close your search handles with [`FindClose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364413(v=vs.85).aspx) rather than leaking them into the ether.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really amateur in programming, could you please write it down step by step?